# Spin n go system [pokerstars or 888]?

Tags: texas-hold-em, poker-strategy, poker-stars

Guys what do you think for regular online players which system is better to stick to in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

888 has a higher rake percentage of 6.12%-10% as opposed to pokerstars' 5%-8%.

888's structure is 4-handed as opposed to pokerstars' 3-handed games. This increases variance.

There is more content available for 3-handed shortstack games, therefore studying will be easier and with more options to choose from. And also, plenty of other sites have 3-handed structures, so your studying can also be applied elsewhere.

To conclude, I think pokerstars is your better pick. However, I don't know the skill level of the players. If you are going to play buy-ins larger than 30 I think 888's playerpool will be softer.

In the end, I don't think there is a huge difference in your hourly rate, but pokerstars has my slight preference.